# Displaying two tables within a loop

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm pretty new to AngularJS.
I'm using it with firebase.

I have a set of data like this one:

```
"userId1" : {
  "name" : "Bobby",
  "comments" : {
    "-J_v90hh5sbJ2acmX4nq" : true
  }
}
```

and a comment list

```
"-J_v90hh5sbJ2acmX4nq" : {
  "creation_date" : 1415110466568,
  "creator_id" : "userId1",
  "desc" : "dsqdsq",
  "type" : "suggest"
}
```

So what I want to do is to display all the comments of our friend Bobby.

```
.controller('CommentsCtrl', function($scope, $firebase){

  var creator_id = 'userId1'; // Test purpose
  var userCommentsRef = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio.com/users/"+creator_id+'/comments');
  var commentsRef = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio.com/comments");


  var userCommentsSync = $firebase(userCommentsRef);
  var commentsSync = $firebase(commentsRef);

  var userComments = userCommentsSync.$asObject();
  var comments = commentsSync.$asObject();

  $scope.userComments = userComments;
  $scope.comments = comments;

})
```

Do you know how I should proceed with this display, but to be sure that if the comments has been deleted (and the key is still there), the description will not be displayed?

```
   <ion-list ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
        <ul class="list">

            <li class="item item-checkbox item-checkbox-right" ng-repeat="(key,item) in userComments">

             {{comments[key].desc}} // Working, but don't want deleted comments 

            </li>

        </ul>
    </ion-list>
```

Is this the correct way to handle this situation?
How can I say to my controller to display only existing comments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter in ng-repeat block in a such way:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,item) in userComments | filter:{deleted:false}">
    {{comments[key].desc}} // Working, but don't want deleted comments 
</li>
```

or, if information stored in comments object use `ng-if`:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,item) in userComments | filter:{deleted:false}" ng-if="!comments[key].deleted">
    {{comments[key].desc}} // Working, but don't want deleted comments 
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the correct way. When working with collections, utilize `$asArray` instead of `$asObject`. From [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-arrays):

Synchronized arrays should be used for any list of objects that will be sorted, iterated, and which have unique ids.

Objects are useful for storing key/value pairs, and singular records that are not used as a collection.

Also, there is no need to have a deleted parameter. You could simply removed the deleted comments from the user's index. Then if it exists in that list, it is not deleted. There is no need for extra filtering fanciness.

That said, you may also want to check out the [new query parameters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries). With those, and a slight data structure change, you could match on items with a property of `deleted` equal to `false`, rather than sorting client-side in Angular.

So all together:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio.com/");

var userCommentsRef = 
    fbRef.child("users" + creator_id + "/comments")
    .orderBy('deleted')
    .startAt(false)
    .endAt(false);

$scope.userComments = $firebase(userCommentsRef).$asArray();
```